# Contact form not working: Notice: Undefined index: message

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I have trouble getting my contact form to work and forward messages to mail.

I receive the following message when i submit my message:

Screenshot : [image]

As far as i know it should be working fine. Furthermore I have used Materialize CSS. The echo messages are in Danish (don't mind those), they just print "Thanks for your message" and "Error".

```
    <?php
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $message = $_POST['message'];
     $formcontent = "Fra: $name \n Besked: $message";
     $recipient = "mail@mail.com";
     $subject = "Kontaktformular";
     $mailheader = "Fra: $email \r\n";
     mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Fejl!");
     echo "Tak for din besked!";
    ?>


  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <form action="mail.php" method="POST" class="col s12">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input  id="name" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="name">Navn</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input id="email" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <textarea id="message" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
              <label for="message">Besked til Safemove</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col m12">
              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light background-orange" type="submit" name="action">Send besked
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: because you are missing `name` attribute in input for all fields.

Comment: missing name attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `name` `attribute` in your all input fields .

```
<input  id="name" name="name" type="text" class="validate">
..                ^^^^^^^^^^          
 <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="validate">
..
 <textarea id="message" name="message" class="materialize-textarea" > </textarea>
```

**Note :** Input without `name attributes` are ignored value not send to server .

Comment: This is a common duplicate question and should not be answered. Instead you should vote to close as a duplicate.